"_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'Ø'." error when using safetensors models in torchserve
I'm trying to run an LLM model using torchserve, mainly following this guide and this quickstart. In particular I'm trying to use the model mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.3, but it doesn't matter since I've tried a lot of different models from different providers.
Some of the models I download can be used with a pytorch_model.bin.index.json, and I'm able to run that just fine, but some others only come indexed with safetensors.model.index.json, and when using this, I get this stacktrace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/rpc/internal.py", line 207, in _run_function
    result = python_udf.func(*python_udf.args, **python_udf.kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/rpc/rref_proxy.py", line 11, in _local_invoke
    return getattr(rref.local_value(), func_name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pippy/PipelineDriver.py", line 282, in create_stage_executor
    mod=mod or Pipe.materialize_stage(mod_name),  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pippy/IR.py", line 1097, in materialize_stage
    submodule = load_checkpoint(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pippy/LoadModule.py", line 45, in load_checkpoint
    checkpoint = torch.load(file_path)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1040, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1262, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'Ø'.

In particular, I think that the line that may be originating this issue is line 45 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pippy/LoadModule.py, since I suspect the torch.load method may need some further tuning to load a safetensors model or something similar. This error is found in multiple entries in a lot of forums, but none of the provided answers work for me (e.g. file is not corrupted or malformatted, and I have safetensors installed).
Is there any tuning that can be done to avoid this error and properly load a model using safetensors?
Edit:
I would also like to mention that I found this question that mentions pickle files having issues when being compressed. However, the library is not mine and I don't think I have control whether they are compressed or not, so could you confirm if this may indeed be the same issue, and in that case, waht would the solution be?
